# Pass user-defined table type from VBA to SQL

Tags: sql, vba, sqldatatypes

I have been tasked with creating an Excel spreadsheet as the front-end to a SQL database and some C# which performs a complicated calculation on the data. My boss wants the front end as a spreadsheet, and the calculation is seemingly too complex for VBA.

Presently, the stored procedure to retrieve the dataset works fine. The user will then edit the data in Excel and send it back to the database. The data needs to be inserted as a new set, preserving the records of the previous sets. I have therefore written the following SQL stored procedure to complete this task:

```
DECLARE @Now DATETIME = GETDATE()
DECLARE @DataSetID SMALLINT = (SELECT ISNULL(MAX([DataSetID]), 0) FROM [dbo].[tbl_DataSet]) + 1

--Add DataSet entry
INSERT INTO [dbo].[tbl_DataSet] ([DataSetID], [InputDate])
SELECT @DataSetID, @Now

--Add latest data
INSERT INTO [dbo].[tbl_Data] ([DataSetID], [DataID], [Amount])
SELECT @DataSetID, [DataID], [Amount]
FROM @DataTable
ORDER BY [DataID]
```

This means that the VBA code needs to be able to call the stored procedure, passing in a user-defined table type parameter, @DataTable AS [dbo].[typ_DataTable] READONLY.

My present method for calling a SQL user stored procedure, passing in standard datatype parameters:

```
Dim cnn As ADODB.Connection
Set cnn = New ADODB.Connection
cnn.ConnectionString = getConnectionString()
cnn.CursorLocation = adUseClient
cnn.Open

Dim cmd As ADODB.Command
Set cmd = New ADODB.Command
cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("in", adInteger, adParamInput, , 1)
cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("bReturn", adBoolean, adParamOutput)
cmd.ActiveConnection = cnn
cmd.CommandText = ProcedureName
cmd.CommandType = adCmdStoredProc

Dim rst As ADODB.Recordset
Set rst = New ADODB.Recordset
Set rst = cmd.Execute()
```

Is there a simple way to pass in user-defined table types?

Alternatively, is there an entirely better system that I can use to do this?

The only work-arounds I can think of at the moment is to pass the data to C#, then send to the database using:

```
command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter {
    ParameterName = "@DataTable",
    Value = dataTable,
    TypeName = "[dbo].[typ_DataTable]",
    SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Structured });
```

However, this seems a little circuitous.

Thanks.

**Update:**

As there is already a pipeline from C# to Excel, it seems best to utilise this one nasty bit of code as opposed to introducing a second with Excel <-> SQL. C# can also be easily used to convert the data types and validate any parameters or return variables. Using pseudo-asynchronous methods with VBA to C# will also improve the Excel interface, preventing hanging on the UI thread.

Comment: Re: *"is there an entirely better system that I can use to do this"* - Yes, anything designed to be a front end, which spreadsheets are not. If you can use the .NET framework it would not be very complicated to have a Gridview populated (either in a windows or web application), edited and the edits sent back to the database.

Comment: Unfortunately, an Excel spreadsheet is demanded. That quote was meant with regards to the database layout and data set insertion method.

Comment: @user1765603, I am trying to do something similar to you. You're saying that you can accomplish passing a table value parameter with your second block of code?

Comment: Elias, that code works for standard data-types but I could not get it to work for table-types. My first solution was to use the pre-existing C# project as the interface between the DB and the Excel front-end, which worked fine. Now, I have subsequently created my own front end as Excel/VBA is not conducive to this sort of project.

Answer (score 0):

ADO has a very nice table type.

> "Presently, the stored procedure to retrieve the dataset works fine. "

Detach the dataset.

> The user will then edit the data in Excel...

Append the new data to the detached dataset. Delete the old data from the detached dataset

> ... and send it back to the database.

Re-Attach the dataset. Update the data:

```
myRecordSet.ActiveConnection=oConnection
myRecordSet.UpdateBatch
```