# Using Table Valued Parameter In A CLR Stored Procedure With A Parameter and Return To Access 2003

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access, stored-procedures, clr

I am trying to create a stored procedure that will take in a Table valued parameter defined as :

```
CREATE TYPE [dbo].[address_tabletype] AS TABLE(
[CONTROL_NUMBER] [varchar](12) NULL,
[ADDRESS1] [varchar](50) NULL,
[ADDRESS2] [varchar](50) NULL,
[CITY] [varchar](50) NULL,
[STATE] [varchar](2) NULL,
[ZIP] [varchar](10) NULL
)
GO
```

The stored procedure will:

- Take this data set
- Manipulate it into a single string
- Execute a third party function that requires the dataset be in a single string
- Take the resulting string and return it to a table valued type
- Return the table valued type OR as the result of a select statement on a local table valued type

After doing a little bit of research I found:

[Using SQL Server 2008 Table-valued Parameters in Access 2007](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd721896(v=office.12).aspx#ac2007usingsqltvparams_tpvsaccessptqs)

Wherein there are two points of interest

> To use a TVP, first create a table type and define its structure in
>   the database.

Which hints to me that it is possible to trick Access into sending and accepting TVPs.

And

> Access pass-through queries, as the name implies, enable you to bypass
>   the Access database engine and to send Transact-SQL code directly to
>   SQL Server for execution. Although pass-through queries can be used to
>   return records, this feature is not available if you want to use
>   table-valued parameters. To use TVPs, you must set the query Returns
>   Records property to No or Access will raise an error. Unfortunately,
>   this means that you will be unable to return any information through
>   the pass-through query mechanism. To get information back from the
>   server, such as new identity values, execute a separate query.

Which hints to me that it is *NOT* possible.

I have been unable to test this, as I do not have Visual Studio to create the C# CLR Function and am asking this to verify if it is worth the effort to go further and if it is possible.

Another individual asked a smiliar question, wherein he found a workaround with C#. Could this work as well?

[Pass user-defined table type from VBA to SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17041519/1504882)

Comment: Why do you need to do this in/from Access?  Access, VBA and their dependence on ADO is the problem here.  ADO.net is the solution, not specifically C# but rather, anything that can use ADO.Net (C#, VB.Net, etc.).

Comment: A lot of in-house applications are in Access(If not all), and thus I must be able to use this from it. This stored procedure is one part of a few, and needs to be seperate for modularization. I agree with you. Any .Net language wherein I could build a CLR is fine, but I was leaning towards C# due to its popularity.

Comment: What you want is probably VSTO for this.  I've never used it on Access, but in Excel that would be the recommended way to get to C#/ADO.Net.

Comment: The C# function would also be using two DLLs, which is why I was trying to centralize it on the server SQLServer was on. Although I do like the idea of VSTO, wouldn't I have to have that installed on each client machine?

Comment: VSTO is the development environment/tool.  However, what you create with it may need to be installed on every client that will use it.  But I'm still not sure if VSTO supports Access or not ...

Comment: My only complaint there is the overhead. The mapping to use the stored procedure would be: Access > .NET > Stored Procedure > .NET > StoredProcedure > .NET > Access. I'll consider that as a solution although I think there may be too many pieces for how arguably simple this step is. Thanks for the help!